# NSThread Timing Problem with GUI

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, user-interface, timing

I have a simple thread that runs an infinite loop. Eventually, the loop will check for serial data at a USB port a few thousand times per second, but at the moment, it just writes something to a custom class of NSTextView once every second.

```
int i;
for (i=1; i>0; i++)
{
    [lock lock];
    [[self textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([[self textStorage] length], 0) withString:@"test\n"];
    [lock unlock];
    sleep(1);
}
```

The issue is that it writes really sporadically. It will do one or two, then wait ten seconds and spit ten of them out at once. If I replace the writing line with an `NSLog(@"test")`, it logs at nice even intervals. I have another test method in the main thread that accepts input into a text field and puts it into the text view, and doing this seems to update the text view to include the child thread's most recent writes. There shouldn't be anything interfering with it at this point anyway, but I've locked everything everywhere just to be sure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the lock object? What do [lock lock] and [lock unlock] do?

Comment: The lock object is an instance of NSLock. Locking code in two different places ensures that they don't happen at the same time. In the above example it's unnecessary, but you should generally use it any time a thread is modifying or reading from a variable that other threads also use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always perform operations that affect the UI from the main thread. You can have the child thread create a temporary object that holds the results, and then use [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a) to call another method that will do the necessary modifications on the main thread.

```
NSString * const MDResultKey = @"MDResult";

- (void)someMethod {
    // 
    int i;
    for (i=1; i>0; i++) {
         // if necessary, create an object to hold results
         NSDictionary *results = [NSDictionary 
               dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"test", MDResultKey, nil];

         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUIWithResults:) 
                  withObject:results waitUntilDone:NO];

         sleep(1);
    }
}


- (void)updateUIWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results {
    NSString *result = [results objectForKey:MDResultKey];
    [lock lock]; // ?
    [[self textStorage] replaceCharactersInRange:
           NSMakeRange([[self textStorage] length], 0) withString:result];
    [lock unlock]; // ?

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally be pretty wary of calling anything on an NSTextStorage on a background thread. I think NSTextView reacts to any NSTextStorage changes, and any UI code on a non-main thread is going to have unpredictable problems.

I would just send the new string to the main thread and call `-replaceCharactersInRange:` there.